# Why can't I print this checkbox array?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to write an array to a variable so that I can print it in a div, however I can't seem to get it right no matter what I do.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" value="1" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" value="3" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" value="4" checked="checked" />
```

Should return 1,3,4

So I have:

```
var variable1 = $('input:checkbox:checked.checkboxes').map(function () {
  return this.value;
  }).get();
  $("#somediv").html(variable1);
```

However the div is empty, does anyone know where I went wrong?

Comment: `.get().toString();` and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the array to a string. Use [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString), if a comma separated list is good enough for your needs:

```
var variable1 = $('input:checkbox:checked.checkboxes').map(function(){
    return this.value;
}).get().toString();
$("#somediv").html(variable1);
```

**Edit**

You can also speed up your selector if you want.

```
$('input:checkbox:checked.checkboxes')
```

Is equivalent to the slightly faster:

```
$('input.checkboxes').filter(':checkbox:checked')
```

And if you don't assign the class `checkboxes` to anything other than a checkbox, the even faster:

```
$('input.checkboxes').filter(':checked')
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. You're the best Paul!

Comment: @pufAmuf You're welcome :) I added an edit for you if you want to speed up your selector a little bit, it's not a huge speedup, but I thought I'd let you know just in case :) Speed test: http://jsperf.com/sadjasdiashuid

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    var data = new Array();
    $('.checkboxes:checked').each(function () {
        data[data.length] = $(this).val();
    });
    $("#somediv").text( data.join(','));
});
```